# How to cross-compile command-line C++ apps for Android on Linux?

Tags: android, c++, linux, qt, gcc

I want to cross-compile simple C++ command line applications for Android on my Linux box. However, I am not sure what packages to install, and once installed how to go about it. My Linux system is a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 VM with g++ and gcc installed.

If possible, I am also looking for support for Qt framework in the applications for Android without using QtCreator (i.e. on the command line).

On Android, I will be using Termux to access and execute the binaries.

Comment: The question mark (?) usually helps when asking the question.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderVX. Question updated.

Comment: Would you please limit your post to one specific question per post

Comment: After you have Qt for Android in the system, provide paths to target qmake from Qt and target GCC. For building Qt for Android target if you don't have that: https://wiki.qt.io/Android

Comment: I believe Qt for Android will fit your requirement. From your question, it seems you could just use the Android NDK without Qt for simple C++ applications.